# Updating a collection of HTML elements within forEach loop

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, foreach, listener

I am trying to update a collection of HTML elements inside a `forEach` loop. Because up to section 3 everything seems to be working, but whenever I try to add new section the problem starts and the buttons in the navigation bar don't work from section 4 and above.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <main id="main">
      <header class="main__hero">
        <nav>
          <ul class="flex-container">
            <li>Section 1</li>
            <li>Section 2</li>
            <li>Section 3</li>
            <li id="new-section">NEW SECTION</li>
            <li id="back">BACK TO TOP</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <h1>Landing Page</h1>
      </header>
      <section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1" class="your-active-class">
        <div class="landing__container">
          <h2>Section 1</h2>
          <p>
          </p>
          <p>
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="section2" data-nav="Section 2">
        <div class="landing__container">
          <h2>Section 2</h2>
          <p>
          </p>
          <p>
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="section3" data-nav="Section 3">
        <div class="landing__container">
          <h2>Section 3</h2>
          <p>
          </p>
          <p>
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
let allSections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
let allLists = document.querySelectorAll("li");
let n = 4;

// This function runs wherever the user press add new section button.
function duplicate(num) {
  const newSection = document.createElement("section");
  const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  const heading = document.createElement("h2");
  const p1 = document.createElement("p");
  const p2 = document.createElement("p");

  newSection.appendChild(newDiv);
  newDiv.appendChild(heading);
  newDiv.appendChild(p1);
  newDiv.appendChild(p2);

  newSection.setAttribute("id", "section" + num);
  newSection.setAttribute("data-nav", "Section" + " " + num);
  newDiv.setAttribute("class", "landing__container");

  heading.textContent = "Section" + " " + num;
  p1.textContent =
    "New text";
  p2.textContent =
    "New text";
  return newSection;
}
// Append the above function to the body.
newSectionBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  newSectionBtn.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", "<li> Section" + " " + n + "</li>");
  main.appendChild(duplicate(n));
  main.lastElementChild.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  n++;
});

// The problem start here...
allLists.forEach((list, index) => {
  list.addEventListener("click", () => {
    allSections[index].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    allSections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
    allLists = document.querySelectorAll("li");
    //console.log("clicked");
  });
});
```

**UPDATE:**
The problem is solved when i put the foreach loop inside:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  allLists.forEach((list, index) => {
    list.addEventListener("click", () => {
      allSections[index].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
      allSections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
      allLists = document.querySelectorAll("li");
    });
  });
});
```

But there is a spamming weird error in the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of undefined
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous>
```

**Any ideas how to fix it?**

Answer (score 0):

I believe whenever you add a new Section, you must also hook up the click event. The `forEach` block runs only once, when the script loads, and thus "knows" only the first 3 section list items.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on this line:

```
allSections[index].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
```

Since you're using the allLists(LI) index to access allSections(section) then you would want to have the same number of sections and li's.

I would recommend adding an `ignore` class to the following `LI` elements:

```
<li class="ignore" id="new-section">NEW SECTION</li>
<li class="ignore" id="back">BACK TO TOP</li>
```

As long as you have the same number of SECTION elements as you have LI elements (excluding the 2 ignored elements), then you shouldn't get the error.

**Update**: I've corrected the following line (there was a # before). Make sure both `allLists` assignments are updated:

```
allLists = document.querySelectorAll("li:not(.ignore)");
```

**Note**: Since the `allLists` loop is now in the `scroll` event, it won't get initialized until the user scolls.

```js
var newSectionBtn = document.getElementById("newSectionBtn");
let allSections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
let allLists = document.querySelectorAll("li:not(.ignore)");
let n = 4;

// This function runs wherever the user press add new section button.
function duplicate(num) {
    const newSection = document.createElement("section");
    const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    const heading = document.createElement("h2");
    const p1 = document.createElement("p");
    const p2 = document.createElement("p");

    newSection.appendChild(newDiv);
    newDiv.appendChild(heading);
    newDiv.appendChild(p1);
    newDiv.appendChild(p2);

    newSection.setAttribute("id", "section" + num);
    newSection.setAttribute("data-nav", "Section" + " " + num);
    newDiv.setAttribute("class", "landing__container");

    heading.textContent = "Section" + " " + num;
    p1.textContent =
        "New text";
    p2.textContent =
        "New text";
    return newSection;
}
// Append the above function to the body.
newSectionBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    newSectionBtn.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", "<li> Section" + " " + n + "</li>");
    main.appendChild(duplicate(n));
    main.lastElementChild.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    n++;
});

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    allLists.forEach((list, index) => {
        list.addEventListener("click", () => {
            allSections[index].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
            allSections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
            allLists = document.querySelectorAll("li:not(.ignore)");
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<button id="newSectionBtn">Hello</button>
<main id="main">
    <header class="main__hero">
        <nav>
            <ul class="flex-container">
                <li>Section 1</li>
                <li>Section 2</li>
                <li>Section 3</li>
                <li class="ignore" id="new-section">NEW SECTION</li>
                <li class="ignore" id="back">BACK TO TOP</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <h1>Landing Page</h1>
    </header>
    <section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1" class="your-active-class">
        <div class="landing__container">
            <h2>Section 1</h2>
            <p>
            </p>
            <p>
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section2" data-nav="Section 2">
        <div class="landing__container">
            <h2>Section 2</h2>
            <p>
            </p>
            <p>
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section3" data-nav="Section 3">
        <div class="landing__container">
            <h2>Section 3</h2>
            <p>
            </p>
            <p>
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
```

Comment: That is right, but still i don't have any ideas how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

To use `forEach` on a HTML collection you'd have to spread it into an array:

```
let allLists = [...document.querySelectorAll("li")];
```

Comment: That's not true.

Comment: You're right. I have no idea where I got that from but I've been doing it this way for a while.